# Android Wear: Override swipe right gesture to prevent the UI to destroy the Activity?

Tags: android

On Android Wear, when you swipe right, the current activity is destroyed.

I'm having two problems because of this:

1. viewpager doesn't work: it's only possible to swipe left, when you try to swipe right the app is closed
2. instead of being stopped the activity is destroyed.

I'm wondering if there is a way to override this.

i have tried OnKeyDown and OnBackpressed but they are not triggered.

Thanks for your help,

Cyril

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775451/how-to-disable-the-android-wear-back-swipe