# Android Wear 2.0 preventing accidental exit of application

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I'm building a Wear 2.0 app and I want to prevent the accidental exiting of the app (swipe from left to right).  How can I "Intercept" the closing of the activity, and abort the closing if the user did not mean to exit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable the android wear back swipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775451/how-to-disable-the-android-wear-back-swipe)