# How can I disable that my Wear OS app closes when I swipe from left to right?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

I did try this but did not work. Do I have to do more? Or is there another easy way?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable the android wear back swipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775451/how-to-disable-the-android-wear-back-swipe)

Comment: You do need to make sure that your theme is being used by your activity. You can also check out this question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775451/how-to-disable-the-android-wear-back-swipe

Answer (score 1):

You can Modify your theme style.
Add this to your style.xml file.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>
</style>
```

Then add theme style in your manifest file on targeted activity like this:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

This will disable swipe in the app or activity.

Comment: where is the style.xml file located ? or do i have to create the file ? Same question for the manifestfile.

Comment: style file is located in values folder which u can see in the image you have uploaded and manifest file is in the manifest folder

Comment: style wasn't a premade file by the android studio. i did add this on my own. is she there right ?

Comment: you have created style file in the string folder, try  to create the file in the values folder then it will work

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` it will make everything white.

Here is a way to do it on a newer device where you didn't add support libraries and also want to make it stay dark theme:

```
<resources>
    <style name="ThemeActivity" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
<activity
     android:name=".ui.MyActivity"
     android:exported="true"
     android:theme="@style/ThemeActivity">
</activity>
```

Disables swipe to close activity on a single activity.